# how to make 3D game physics or collision detection

Tags: collision, game-physics

I really need to know how to make collision detection. I can only do axis-aligned-bounding-boxes. I have heard of other methods. I heard of something called a minimal oobb. but I can't figure them out. I'm still in school and I'm pretty good at math. But I don't know the first thing about physics. I know I could use Bullet physics but I really would like to know how to do it myself. I don't really know about anything other than aabbs and oobbs. and as I said before, aabbs are all I can do. So please show me what methods there are and where I can learn how to do them. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish.  If you are doing this for learning, by all means dig into various methods of simulating physics.  But if you are trying to create an application that requires simulated physics, do not reinvent the wheel.  Do some searching and I am sure you will find existing libraries you can use.

Comment: I know I can use a library  but I want to know how to do it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this book is best for you...

[http://www.amazon.com/Real-Time-Collision-Detection-Interactive-Technology/dp/1558607323](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607323)

Comment: I'll consider it. I was hoping for an online explanation but I guess everything ain't for free. I'll try to look a little longer but if nothing else I'll buy it. thanks for the answer